# UICollectionView - How to set background color of a row

Tags: ios, swift, background, uicollectionview, row

I have a `UICollectionView` and only one section. Is there a way to set the background color of every row? (in my case it would be a gradient from black to white)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CollectionViews don't really have a concept of a rows because it's designed to have a flexible layout.

Your best option is likely to have the background of the cells have your pattern and remove all the padding/margin between the cells.

This will be a problem if the last row isn't full, so if the number needs to be flexible you would have to add empty cells.

Comment: If you're going to have a consistent layout, you might consider using a tableView instead.

Comment: I have/need a UICollectionView - its only about the design

Answer (score 0):

You can set on color on cell using `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];`

else for gradient you have to layer and set to cell like below code

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```